# Calculating elapsed time in Excel sheet using macro

Tags: excel, vba

My Excel sheet looks like the following:

```
A---------------------B---------------------C  
Intime----------------Outtime---------------Elapsedtime  
10:00 AM--------------  
11:00 AM--------------  
9:00 AM
```

I want to calculate on Column C only when I enter data on Column B and this should be done using Macro.

Comment: What gets entered into Column B?

Comment: Why a macro?  If columns A and B contain Excel times, I would set C2 to "=IF(B2="","",B2-A2)" and copy down.  Note, an Excel time is a number between 0 (00:00:00) and .999988 (23:23:59).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range) 'when entering data in a cell in Col B
On Error GoTo enditall
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Cells.Column = 2 Then
        n = Target.Row
    If Me.Range("B" & n).Value <> "" Then
        Me.Range("C" & n).Value = Format(Me.Range("B" & n).Value - Me.Range("A" & n).Value, "hh:mm:ss")
    End If
    End If
enditall:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Right-click on the sheet tab and "View Code".

Paste the code into that sheet module.

Alt + q to return to the Excel window.